# A quicker way to get the other emails of the sender

Tags: gmail

Previously, while reading an email in gmail, when you hover your mouse on the sender's avatar you had an option to see the previous email of the sender. That link is apparently removed and now I have to do a manual search (`from:jonh@exmpale.com`) to access the communications history of the sender. Is there still a quicker way?

Answer (score 1):

The current fastest way that I know of is to make an automatic search:

Select *Filter messages like this* in the email options (three vertical dots right to the fav and reply buttons). That option will automatically search all the emails of the sender. An emerging formulary will pop up and you'll have to close or ignore it.

I hope that this is faster than your manual search.